# Where can I report error of libncurses.so?

Tags: linux

Hello and no offense,

I cannot see the forest at moment, because there are too many trees ...

In Linux there is a file called libncurses.so - to which library or to which package does
this file belong ? I want to know where I can report errors of this file.

This file is in every Linux-Distro and is no specific file ?!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`INSTALL` file of the ncurses package](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ncurses/-/blob/master/INSTALL):

> Send any feedback to the ncurses mailing list at
> bug-ncurses@gnu.org. To subscribe send mail to
> bug-ncurses-request@gnu.org with body that reads:
> subscribe ncurses

Caveat: although it is always useful to report bugs, `ncurses` is on millions of systems, and from personal experience the chances that a random user like you and me uncovers a real bug are pretty slim, usually it is more a misunderstanding of how something works. Also, make sure that you are running the latest version (especially if you use a RHEL derivative, these tend to use quite ancient code).

Comment: thank you very much !!!